# VS Code Extension Not Showing "HELLO WORLD" Command in Debug Mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm attempting to develop a VS Code extension, following the [documentation provided here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension). After creating the extension, I ran it using the Debug (F5) mode.

Subsequently, in the opened window, I pressed Cmd + Shift + P and entered `Hello World`, expecting to see the related command. However, the command did not appear.

How can I effectively debug this issue with my VS Code extension?
[image]

Comment: does it work if you copy the example code from the repo

Comment: It worked! I'll check the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your VS Code version is lower than the version required in your extension. Try updating your VS Code to latest version and run the extension again.

Comment: Thank you. My VSCode is Version: 1.82.3. This is latest version. However I downgraded engines to `^1.74.0`. Now It's works!